# Какой вариант инициализации экземпляров предпочтительнее?

Tags: java, android

Где лучше инициализировать экземпляры: сразу, объявляя их в глобальных переменных или в методе onCreate()? Попробовал – вроде бы работают оба способа. Но как все таки правильнее?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Смотря где и когда будете использовать...

Если использовать будете ещё до вызова `onCreate()`, и если нет зависимости (от `View`, от того, что создаётся в `onCreate()` и т.п.), то без разницы. Можно сразу, чтобы не нужно было запариваться с проверкой на `null`. Собственно, если есть зависимость - то в `onCreate()`.